# entity framework query take much time, timeout exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If i test it **Select * from TableName where Id = 257**  then i get one record and query execute in some seconds, but when **Select * from TableName** then it shows thousand of records and it takes more than 3 minutes to execute.

I am using this statement in entity framework and i get timeout exception always:

```
TableName tbl= db.TableName.Where(o => o.ID == 257).FirstOrDefault();
```

Does it first selects all records from db and then apply where on it, thats why it is taking much time or there is any other reason?

Please guide me.

Thanks.

Comment: Check generated SQL and see what's being sent to database.

Comment: I checked in profiler but there no query shown related to this table, may be its because i get error on this line.

Comment: If its not executing then how are you managed to see the data. It appears that you are not profiling it correctly. If the query is executing then you should be able to profile using SQL Profiler (assuming you are using SQL server) or EF logging http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469464.aspx

Comment: Is it while debugging or also without debugging? Is your connection string correct?

Comment: connection string is correct. when i debug or without bebug then it gives error on this line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like

```
var query = db.TableName.Where(x => x.ID == 257);
Console.WriteLine(query.ToString());
```

to see what sql is generated by EF.

When you say

```
Select * from TableName then it shows thousand of records and it takes more than 3 minutes     to execute.
```

This is expected behavior since there is not condition.

but you EF query doesn't reflect the same.

and have where clause. Just a wild guess check if your Table is index on ID
you can also try to use

```
TableName tbl= db.TableName.Find(257);
```

while will execute much faster because it can give you result back from its cache.

**Update**
You can also used sql profiling tool called "Entity Framework Profiler"

http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/efprof

its very good tool i had used it personally.

Comment: ToTraceString(); is a method? it says not found.

Comment: My Bad, ToTraceString will work on linq http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.totracestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Generally as long as you operate against IQueryable collections in your Linq queries, the operation builds SQL  statement and does not query a database. It queries a database and finally materialises the collection if you use such actions as: ToList(), FirstOrDefault() or you simply start to iterate over the collection.

   So it is always better to build Linq statement using the IQueryable collections (instead of List). So, in this case when you use Linq extensions methods (fluent pattern mode) the methods like Where always returns IQueryable collection.
2. If you get time consuming rows' collection and you are not going to submit changes to it (only reading) you   have possibility to turn off ChangeTracking function as well as Validation during saving data to a database:

   `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;`

In some situations it brings great improvement of performance.